# Random variable created with scipy.stats and multiprocessing : Pickle error

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, multiprocessing

I'm no king in python, and recently got in trouble with a modification I made in my code. My algorithm is basically multiple uses of stochastic gradient algorithm and thus needs random variables.

I wanted my code to handle custom random variables and probability distribution. To do so, I modified my code and now I use scipy.stats to draw samples of custom random variables. Basically, I create a random variable with an imposed probability density or a cumulative density, and then draw samples thanks to the inverse function of the cumulative distribution function and some uniform random variable between [0,1].

To make it simple the algorithm runs multiple optimization from different starting point using stochastic gradient algorithm, and thus can be parallelized since the starting points are independent.

Problem is that the random variable created this way can't be pickled

> PicklingError: Can't pickle : attribute lookup **builtin**.instancemethod failed

I don't get the subtility of pickling problems for now, so if you guys can help me solve this following simple illustration of the problem :

```
RV = scipy.stats.norm();
def Draw(rv,N):
   return rv.ppf(np.random.random(N))
pDraw = partial(Draw,RV);
PM = multiprocessing.pool(Processes = 2);
L = PM.map(pDraw,range(1,5));
```

I've heard of pathos library that do not use the same serialization algorithm (dill), but I would like to avoid this solution (if it is a solution) as it is not included in my python distribution at work... making it install will take a lot of time.

Comment: Try *freezing* your distribution.

Comment: In my little illustration, as I use basic distribution, RV is a rv_frozen object. Still this simple illustration gives the same error.